# Monitoring new likes and automatically sending a private message

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would need to write a script in order to automate this task:

1. Monitor new likes on a Facebook Page periodically.
2. When a new like is detected, identify the person who gave it
3. Send them a private message, thanking them and pointing them to additional resources that may be of their interest.

Would this be feasible using the Facebook API? The documentation strikes me as a little unwelcoming for the casual observer, and I'm not sure whether this is impossible or it's just that I haven't dived deep enough. Are the three steps above doable using the API?

Comment: That would not be allowed. Just because a user likes your page, does not give you the right to contact them.

Comment: Understood. We were wondering whether there would be an equivalent of Twitter automation features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use a cron job to get the number of likes of a Page with the [`/page-id`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page) endpoint.
2. You can´t get the fans of a Page with the API, and you can´t get the "last liker" either.
3. Auto-sending and message prefilling is not allowed (it would be spam anyway), and you can only reply to use messages as a Page. You can´t initiate a conversation.

Comment: I had hoped there would be a way to get who the last liker is, as we can see this information in the notifications section. As for (3), I understand why it is not allowed, but we were wondering if it would be possible because Twitter does allow to send a direct message to your followers.